# Last.fm scrobblers ( websites / add-ons ... )

Tags: last.fm

What websites or add-ons allows you to listen to music and scrobble it to your last.fm ?
I know few like ;

- [The Hype Machine website](http://hypem.com/)  : based on music from blogs
- [Universal Scrobbler add_on](http://lastfmstats.livefrombmore.com/universalscrobbler/) : allows you to scrobble from Myspace, MusicBrainz and more...

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** Rdio was discontinued at the end of 2015 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdio)).

[Rdio](http://www.rdio.com/)

> Rdio is a music service, where you
> discover music through your friends
> and followers. Rdio works in the
> browser, on the desktop, and on
> Android, BlackBerry and iPhone
> smartphones. Rdio also provides music
> downloads.

[image]

Comment: looks interesting, i sent a request to register :)

Answer (score 1):

If you include add-ons for hardware, then I scrobble with the Last.fm add-in for [Logitech Squeezebox players](http://www.last.fm/group/Logitech+Squeezebox+Scrobblers), and with the [Last.fm app for my Android](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.fm-last-android-jwmx.aspx) phone.

Also [Spotify will scrobble](http://www.spotify.com/int/help/faq/tech/scrobble-support/) your plays, if you set it up to.

Comment: unfortunately Spotify is not available in my country..